# How to Update _Subscribers DE with Records from Email Send Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber, email-studio, data-views

I recently setup the following:

- Created an Email SendLog using Template
- Added 3 unique customer identifiers to the Email SendLog
- Added BusinessUnitID and the same 3 unique customer identifiers in the Profile Management section
- The Profile Management updates automatically added the same fields to the 'All Subscribers' list and the _EnterpriseAttribute table

When reviewing how to update 'All Subscriber' data for the new fields I added, I sounds like I need to join the _EnterpriseAttribute  with _Subscribers table but I've come to find I have no one in _Subscribers even though we've emailed over 900K that exist in the All Subscriber table.

My questions are:

1. Do companies have to setup their own custom processes to insert records into the _Subscribers table or is this something that should happen automatically after email send or via a setting in the connector from Sales Cloud?
2. I read elsewhere the 'Add Method' is key in linking Marketing Cloud email sends back to Sales Cloud, even if you're using a Salesforce Data Extension since they won't be recognized unless the 'Add Method' for these subscribers = 'SalesforceSubscriber' as opposed to 'CustomObject'. If I have to create a process for question 1, can I hard-code 'SalesforceSubscriber' as the Add Method?

Appreciate any and all help.. thanks!

Comment: I believe you are querying in the child bu. You need to use ent._subscriber

Comment: YESSSSSS, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are using the _Subscriber data view in a child BU you must use ENT._Subscriber.

[SQL Query Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5)

> If your account is a child account in an Enterprise, you can query shared data extensions in the parent account. First, ensure that the Sharing tab information in Contact Builder is set up. Prefix the data extension name in the query with ENT.

Answer (score 0):

_subscriber stores only hidden list for trigger sends.

When you are querying the subscriber you should always use ent. Prefix because subscribers resides at parent level not child level